# Cancelled Google Calendar Event empty properties and missing extendedproperties

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

When fetching a list of Google Calendar Events (v3) using a `syncToken`, most properties of the returned event are empty when its status is 'cancelled'.

For my synchronisation programme, I need to be able to get my unique key from the `ExtendedProperties` collection. This property seems to be missing from the Event. I could, of course, use the ICalUID to match both records, but that means rewriting the whole thing.

Is there a way to get all the properties the Event once had when its status is now Cancelled?

Comment: To get the list of all properties of an cancelled event, while sending request to events.list, give showDeleted='true', which also includes the list of cancelled events in the response.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I read in the documentation it isn't required to use `showDeleted=true` when using a `syncToken`, but it didn't say anything about missing properties! =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get all the properties by setting showDeleted=true on the list request.

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks! It's a shame that the v3 API documentation isn't quite complete.